# How do I calculate the exponent of a certain number without multiplying it by itself over and over again?

Tags: computational-mathematics

I have a number 'x' raised to 'n', and I want to calculate the x^n without x.x.x.x....(n times). How do I do that? Is it possible to do it without the tedious self-multiplication?

(I mean to do it without computers)

I've been suggested using logarithms, but how efficient are they and do they have a limit?

Thanks!

Comment: Use logarithms and exponentiation

Comment: $x^n= \exp(n\log_e(x))$ if $x>0$.  Or the old fashioned way using tables which avoids even a single multiplication: $10\hat{}(10\hat{}(\log_{10}(n)+\log_{10}(\log_{10}(x))))$ if $x>1$

Comment: What do you mean by "calculate"? I guess you mean calculate with pencil and paper, since most calculators and computer algebra systems ([even typing into google](https://www.google.com/search?q=5%5E9)) allow for exponentiations to be calculated without repeated multiplication (by the user). Here's one way: Say you want to calculate $5^{14}$ (in the sense of obtaining a base-10 numeral for the value). Squaring $5$ successively gives $5^2,$ $5^4,$ $5^8.$ Now multiply $5^4$ and $5^8$ together to get $5^{12},$ a process that involves a total of $4$ multiplications (two of which are a bit lengthy).

Answer (score 0):

This can be achieved in O(lg(n)) time:

```
    double exponent(double x, uint32_t n)  {
        double result = 1.0;
        while (n > 0u)
        {
           if ((n % 2) == 1)
           {
              result *= x;
              n--;
           }
          n = n / 2;
          x = x * x;
        }
        return result;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's @Vectorizer 's $O(\log n)$ solution as a recursive function.
$$\mathrm{pow}(x,n) = \begin{cases} 
x & \textrm{, if } n=1\\
\mathrm{pow}\left(x^2,\dfrac{n}{2}\right) & \textrm{, if } n \textrm{ is even}\\
x\cdot \mathrm{pow}\left(x^2,\dfrac{n-1}{2}\right) & \textrm{, if } n \textrm{ is odd}
\end{cases}$$